# How to take advantage of mkNumericOps in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I'm trying to define a new type that can behave essentially like a number (for concreteness, let's say a `Double`). I'd like to overload operators on this type and I could do this explicitly, but to avoid repetition, I would like to advantage of the methods in [`NumericOps`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric$NumericOps.html), which are defined in terms of the abstract methods in [`Numeric`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html). My understanding is I should be able to just override the methods in `Numeric` and get the others for free.

Here's the simplest attempt I can think of:

```scala
class Container(val value: Double) extends Numeric[Container] {
  override def plus(x: Container, y: Container): Container =
    new Container(x.value + y.value)

  // override minus, times, etc.

  override def toString: String = value.toString
}

println(new Container(1) + new Container(1))
```

However, this gives me a type mismatch error.

My understanding of implicits is still quite shaky, but I would have thought the `implicit def mkNumericOps(lhs: Container): NumericOps` inherited by `Container` would save the day by implicitly converting the two `Container` objects being added to `NumericOps` objects and then adding them using the `+` method defined in terms of `Container.plus`.

What am I getting wrong here and how can I fix this?

Comment: Why not import `container.mkNumericOps`?

Comment: You are not using the **typeclass** as appropriated. Your type shouldn't extend `Numeric` itself, but rather, you should proof that your type has a `Numeric`. Finally, you should `import Numeric.Implicits._` at the beginning of the code to provide all the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example to supplement Luis' typeclass comment

```
final case class Container(value: Double)

object Container {
  implicit val containerNumeric: Numeric[Container] = new Numeric[Container] {
    override def plus(x: Container, y: Container) = Container(x.value + y.value)
    override def minus...
  }
}

import Numeric.Implicits._
Container(1) + Container(1)
```

which outputs

```
res0: Container = Container(2.0)
```

The import provides [`infixNumericOps`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric$$Implicits$.html#NumericOps) which compiler uses to automatically rewrite to

```
infixNumericOps(Container(1)) + Container(1)
```

Comment: Thanks Mario, I was about to add my answer. Just one minor comment. AFAIK, it is a bad practice to import implicits by their name, since those could change in any moment. Thus, it is recommended to just `import Numeric.Implicits._`

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `mkNumericOps` from an instance of `Container`:

```
val container = new Container(1)
import container.mkNumericOps
println(container + container)
```

You can omit importing by defining your own `+` method via `mkNumericOps` like so:

```
def +(y: Container): Container = mkNumericOps(this) + y
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I avoid the `import` statement here? I believe there should be a way by defining an appropriate implicit value or function in a companion object for `Container`, but I can't quite see how this works...

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that using a companion object because each instance "has its own" `mkNumericOps`. You can omit importing by defining your own `+` method via `mkNumericOps` like so: `def +(y: Container): Container = mkNumericOps(this) + y`

Comment: worth noting that for default Numerics those import are done in Predef, which is loaded before every code execution (unless you explicitly disable that)

Comment: @dveim Could you provide an example? Feel free to edit my answer for complementing

Comment: e.g. `implicit def intWrapper(x: Int): runtime.RichInt = new runtime.RichInt(x)`. It's more about "how to avoid explicit import statement" question. And, well, one can change the Predef to import custom code by default.