# Scala-Lang recommended import statement style: package._ or package.ClassName?

Tags: scala, import

Looking for best Scala-Lang practice for import statements. Don't see any recommendation here:

1. https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#packages
2. https://github.com/scala/scala

So what is recommended?

Option (1):

```
import package._
```

Option (2):

```
import package.ClassName
```

Comment: None is recommended over the other. If you want to import few then use `yourpackage.Class1`. If you have to import too many of them then use `yourpackage._`.  The demarkation between "few" and "too many" is a subjective thing.

Comment: Don't forget about `import package.{ClassName1, ClassName2, ClassName3}`.

Answer (score 4):

This is generally a matter of taste, but there is an argument for avoiding `._` so that the code is more robust to library changes that might introduce unwanted symbols into your code or create other subtle changes to your code that are difficult to track down.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding implicits, wildcard imports have a potential [advantage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59711985/how-to-take-advantage-of-mknumericops-in-scala/59716669#comment105586719_59716669) in that the name of the implicit can change without having to fix the import statements, for example, consider

```
object Qux {
  object Implicts {
    implicit class ExtraListOps[T](l: List[T]) {
      def shuffle: List[T] = scala.util.Random.shuffle(l)
    }
  }
}

import Qux.Implicts._
List(1,2,3,4,5).shuffle
```

Here we could rename `ExtraListOps` and yet would not have to modify import statement. On the other hand, Joshua Suereth [states](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/as_riGt3QIQ/EiRWA5oTChQJ):

> You can pull implicits in individually without wildcards.  Explicit
>   imports have 'priority' over wildcard imports.  Because of this, you
>   can shadow wildcard imports with an explicit import.

Also consider the discussion in the SIP [Wildcard imports considered harmful](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/wildcard-imports-considered-harmful/3580), where for example, Ichoran [states](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/wildcard-imports-considered-harmful/3580/2?u=mario-galic)

> Superfluous clutter at the top of every file that can only be managed
>   by an IDE, and even then not very well, is something I find a lot more
>   harmful in most cases. If you get conflicting implicits and the
>   compiler doesn’t tell you exactly where they came from, that’s a
>   compiler issue. Once detected, the fix is easy enough (e.g. `import org.foo.{troublesomeImplicit => _, _}`).